# Display an image in Blazorise Datagrid

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I am currently working on an app which is supposed to display names, phone numbers, e-mails... and **pictures**. I've looked around on the internet to find out how to do it, but no results. Does anyone knows how to display an image in a cell ?

Thanks,

Romain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to my question. To display an image, you simply have to use the `<DisplayTemplate>` element. Inside the `<DisplayTemplate>` block, you have to create a variable that will be an instance of your model.

Here is a quick exemple on how to do it:

```
...
<DataGridColumn TItem="MyModel" Field="@nameof(MyModel.Picture)" caption="">
    <DisplayTemplate>
        @{
            var myModel = context as MyModel;
            <img src="@myModel.Picture"/>
        }
    </DisplayTemplate>
</DataGridColumn>
...
```